# Problems with install 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer beside WIN8. I have started install it by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069) guide.
When I start the installation I got this message:

```
This computer currently has no detected operation systems. What would you like to do?
*Erase disk and install Ubuntu
*Somthing else
```

Because I have WIN8 installed in my computer, I have chosen "Somthing else".

Than I got this screen:

[image: screen]
if there is problems with the image try [this](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0BxUA5tVvidGpY0J5bnk3eTFRSWc&export=download) link.

The first 4 lines is the Hard disk(first line-general,2nd-WIN*, 3th-none,4th-I want to install here). the last 2 lines is another USB stick.

I tried choosing in the table and in the choose-box the partition I need and it gaves me this error mesage:

> No root file system is defined.
>
> Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

What do I need to do?

**EDIT:now I see that I destroyed my WIN8 with tose games**

**EDIT2: I don't know what did I do but when I'm tring to re-install WIN8 I see that I didn't format the disk and the files is there (I see that the drive have in-use space) but windows dosn't works and the comuter says that it isn't proper boot device. what the hell is going here?**

Comment: Can you check the link to the image?

Comment: @krishnakaanthh works? in my computer I see it perfect. I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, you don't have any free space on your hard drive, you have ntfs and fat32 partitions. You need to shrink your windows partition, and free up some disk space. Is that definitely a Windows 8 hard drive, I don't see the EFI partition.

Anyway...

Try the instructions on this link instead, they do work.

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Do I need EFI partiation? or which partiation(s) I do need?

Comment: Windows 8 uses an EFI partition, so you will have one by default. I can't work out, from your screenshot, exactly what is going on.  As far as I am aware, windows 8 generates a recovery  partition, am EFI partition, a system partition and a main windows ntfs partition. You would shrink the windows ntfs partition to make space for Ubuntu. Is this a pre-installed version of windows 8 ? Would you be against wiping your hard drive completely and re-installing windows, then follow the guide on dual booting Ubuntu ?

Comment: Now I installed Ubuntu successfully on the 3th partition(and I changed it's type to ex4) and my problem in windows is because it's partition changed to un-bootable during the process. I have now more problems with Ubuntu and the dual-booting but now this question isn't realevant. thank's.